# Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found

Tags: 16.04, mongodb

For whatever reason, whenever I try to start MongoDB as a service (sudo service mongod start) I get the following error:

Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
 I followed Installation Steps mention following link
[mongo db installation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04)  failed

```
system> sudo systemctl start mongodb
Failed to start mongodb.service: Unknown unit: mongodb.service
```

And when I try `sudo mongod`:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.13 connecting to: - 
2017-06-03T16:19:28.513+0530 W NETWORK [thread1] 
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused 
2017-06-03T16:19:28.514+0530 E QUERY [thread1] 
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14 @(connect):1:6 exception: connect failed
```

And when I try `mongod --repair`:

```
2017-06-03T16:32:35.514+0530 I CONTROL [initandlisten] 
MongoDB starting : pid=17423 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=sid-Ideapad-Z570 2017-06-03T16:32:35.514+0530 I 
CONTROL [initandlisten] db version v3.2.13 [listen] target_arch: x86_64 2017-06-03T16:32:35.514+0530 I 
CONTROL [initandlisten] options: {} 2017-06-03T16:32:35.540+0530 I STORAGE [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
```

Comment: What's the output of this command : `ls /etc/systemd/system | grep mongo` Output ?

Comment: out put is 
mongodb.service

Comment: Do you have this file ? `/usr/bin/mongod`;  if you have what the output of this command `sudo mongod`

Comment: `MongoDB shell version: 3.2.13
connecting to: -
2017-06-03T16:19:28.513+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2017-06-03T16:19:28.514+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed`

Comment: try `mongod --repair` then `sudo mongod`; it's may be helpful

Comment: Also try `sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock` then `mongod --repair` and then `sudo mongod` . And check the output

Comment: `2017-06-03T16:32:35.514+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=17423 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=sid-Ideapad-Z570
2017-06-03T16:32:35.514+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.13
[listen]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-06-03T16:32:35.514+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-06-03T16:32:35.540+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59803/discussion-between-siddharth-jain-and-ali76).

Comment: This command me helpful for you : `sudo mkdir -p /data/db && sudo chmod 755 /data/db && sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /data/db`

Comment: Found this, which fixed it for me without having to reinstall.
http://nmp90.com/2017/05/failed-start-mongod-service-unit-mongod-service-not-found-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Please [edit] this question and put the details asked for in the text of the question itself instead of hiding them in comments. Comments can be deleted, and are not strictly part of the Q&A.

Comment: try this ```sudo systemctl daemon-reload```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I reinstalled mongod-org, since my data will still stay safe.

The problem was that my system couldn't find mongod.service when I ran `sudo service mongod status`.

Running this fixed it and restored the service:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

Then all I had to do was copy my correct config to `/etc/mongod.conf` and run

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Comment: I was trying to enable mongod, but it shows `Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory`

Comment: Just noting that this works when you have installed mongodb community edition from the mongodb repos

Comment: Try : `sudo service mongodb status`

Answer (score 20):

This has worked for me.

1. Uninstall your mongo completely from your system:

   ```
   sudo service mongod stop 
   sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org* 
   sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb 
   sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
   ```
2. Now reinstall mongodb using following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
   echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
   ```

   To install a specific release, you must specify each component package individually along with the version number, as in the following example:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.6.0 mongodb-org-server=3.6.0 mongodb-org-shell=3.6.0 mongodb-org-mongos=3.6.0 mongodb-org-tools=3.6.0
   ```
3. Now you can see mongod working but still the same issue is bothering you. The issue is that your system couldn't find mongod.service when you run `sudo service mongod status`.

   Running this fixed it and restored the service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable mongod
   ```
4. Now you're all set to use mongo.

   ```
   sudo service mongod restart
   ```

Comment: I have done your guide but I am getting following error: `Failed to enable unit: Unit file mongod.service does not exist.` @Akash Jain

Comment: I had success following this, but at step 3 I did `sudo systemctl enable mongodb` and for step 4 I did `sudo systemctl start mongodb`.  Note the  unexpected `b` in mongodb instead of just mongod.

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the exact problem mentioned by OP, even though I installed Mongodb using the official install tutorial (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ ),

NOTE: in step 2 of the tutorial (create a list file for Mongodb), it is important to click on the tab specific to the particular version of Ubuntu on your machine. By default it shows Ubuntu 14.04, which created the problems mentioned by OP (Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found)

When I finally noticed that in step 2 I had to properly select Ubuntu 16.04 (for me), the install was successful and after this mongod ran without any issues.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice the version tabs either! Uninstalled as in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#uninstall-mongodb-community-edition then followed the install again with the appropriate version.